How to programmatically add input to an Azure Devops YAML pipeline task
Consider the Azure Devops Pipeline template below:
parameters:
  - name: projectName
    type: string
  - name: projectKey
    type: string
  - name: sonarHostUrl
    type: string

 - task: SonarQubePrepare@6
    inputs:
      SonarQube: 'SonarQubeOnDocker'
      projectKey: ${{parameters.projectKey}}
      projectName: ${{parameters.projectName}}
      extraProperties: |
        sonar.host.url=${{ parameters.sonarHostUrl }}
        # Additional properties that will be passed to the scanner.
        # Put one key=value per line, example:
        # sonar.exclusions=**/*.bin
        # sonar.verbose=true
        # sonar.sources=src/
        # sonar.tests=src/
        # sonar.exclusions=/_/**/*

This template, which prepares SonarQube for analysis, is part of a dedicated Git repo that only contains reusable YAML templates; these templates are in turn used in several pipelines. This particular template is not used by any pipeline directly, instead it is used by yet another generic template that builds a .NET solution. Therefore, if I want to add the property sonar.exclusions, I can add another item to the parameters block, but I would have to add the same parameter to the caller. If I continue to do that for all other SonarQube related properties, the list of parameters will become very large.
Instead of expanding the number of parameters of this template, I was wondering if I could populate the properties that go under the extraProperties programmatically (note that each property must be on a separate line). If that is even possible, I would like to know if I can first use Powershell to read a file that extracts the various SonarQube related properties, and subsequently add them to the extraProperties.

Why don't you generate a sonar-project.properties file programmatically and set  the configFile property instead?

In a related question that I posted yesterday (see link at the end), I concluded that using scannerMode=cli does not work properly for C#, and when I read the documentation of SonarQubePrepare@6 I see that configFile is to be used when scannerMode=cli.  ` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79044177/in-azure-devops-pipeline-how-to-perform-sonarqube-analysis-for-net-project-usi/)

I finally found a solution to my objective, which was to have a file sonar-project.properties, whose properties could be provided to the SonarQubePrepare task for a .NET project, i.e. for which the scannerMode is MsBuild.
First I have a Powershell task that will create a variable $sqExtraProperties containing properties that always need to be passed to SonarQubePrepare. The Powershell snippet will furthermore search for the sonar-project.properties file, and if found, read the SonarQube related properties and add that to $sqExtraProperties. This is an output variable of the Powershell task, and can be used inSonarQubePrepare.
The part that was really difficult, was to make $sqExtraProperties a multi-line variable. In Powershell you'd normally use "`n", but that did not work, instead I had to resolve to the solution presented in this SO question.
My final solution looked like this:
parameters:
  - name: projectName
    type: string
  - name: projectKey
    type: string
  - name: sonarHostUrl
    type: string
  - name: pathToSonarQubeConfigFile
    type: string
    default: ''

- powershell: | 
      
      $sqExtraPropertiesSingleLine = "sonar.host.url=${{ parameters.sonarHostUrl }}"
      $pathToConfigFile = '${{ parameters.pathToSonarQubeConfigFile }}'
      if(($pathToConfigFile  -ne '') -and (Test-Path $pathToConfigFile)){        
        $contents = Get-Content -Path $pathToConfigFile

        #Get lines starting with "sonar" -> trim -> append to sqExtraPropertiesSingleLine using ; as newline delimiter
        $contents | Where-Object {$_ -match "^\s*sonar"} | ForEach-Object {$trimmedLine = $_.Trim(); $sqExtraPropertiesSingleLine = "$sqExtraPropertiesSingleLine;$trimmedLine"}
      }

      # See link to other SO question for url encoding of multi-line string
      $sqExtraProperties = $sqExtraPropertiesSingleLine -replace ';', "%0D%0A"

      # Make $sqExtraProperties available to the next task
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sqExtraProperties;]$sqExtraProperties"
  

 - task: SonarQubePrepare@6
    inputs:
      SonarQube: 'SonarQubeOnDocker'
      projectKey: ${{parameters.projectKey}}
      projectName: ${{parameters.projectName}}
      extraProperties: |
         $(sqExtraProperties)


I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can read the Properties in file and pass to the sonarqube task in single Pipeline.
When we read the properties in file, we need to use logging command(echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=xx;]xx") to set Pipeline variable to pass the value. But Azure DevOps doesn't support Multi-line variable when using logging command to set the variable. So this method can not be achieved in single pipeline.
For a workaround, we can use two pipelines to achieve it. One is used to read the properties in file and trigger the other pipeline, the other pipeline will use object type parameters to collect the multiple line value and pass to sonarqube task.
Here is an example:
properties file Content:
|\n sonar.exclusions=**/*.bin\n sonar.verbose=true\n sonar.tests=src/

Pipeline One:
steps:
- powershell: |
    $filecontent = Get-Content "properties.txt"

    echo $filecontent
   
    $token = "$(PAT)"      
    $url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectNmae}/_apis/pipelines/{PipelineDefinitionID}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"

    $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

    $JSON = "
    {
      


      `"resources`": {
        `"repositories`": {
          `"self`": {
            `"ref`": `"refs/heads/master`"
          }
        }
      },
      `"templateParameters`": {
        `"InputProperties`":`"$($filecontent)`"
      },



    }"


    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json  

Pipeline Two:
Main Pipeline:
parameters:
  - name: InputProperties
    type: object

       
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
    Properties: ${{parameters.InputProperties}}

Template:
parameters:
  - name: Properties
    type: object

       


steps:

- task: SonarQubePrepare@6
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'SonarQubeOnDocker'
    organization: 'xx'
    scannerMode: 'xx'
    projectKey: 'xx'
    projectName: 'xx
    extraProperties: ${{parameters.Properties}}

In addition, if you want to keep using a single pipeline, you need to manually define parameters to set extraProperties inputs based on actual requirement.
